# Window for UIViewController: avoid touching UIApplication

Tags: ios, uikit

Is there a way to get the window or a scene UIViewController belongs to
without idiotic trip to UIApplication?

The idea behind dodging that anti-pattern of assuming UIWindow is a singleton
to have code that's potentially portable to macos. Or at least to iOS extensions:
as far as I remember UIApplication is not extension safe API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIViewController` has a `view` property of type `UIView`. `UIView` has a `window` property of type `UIWindow`. `UIWindow` has a `windowScene` property of type `UIWindowScene`.

As long as the view controller is visible, you can get the window with:

```
self.view.window
```

where `self` is the view controller instance.

If the view controller's view is not currently in the window hierarchy then the `window` property is `nil`.